# Function does not return a value actionscript guessing game

Tags: actionscript-3

I am very new to programming in actionscript.  I just recently learned about functions and my assignment was to create a guessing game where the user inputs a range and the computer will generate a random number within this range.  The user then guesses what the number is.

My main problem is that I get the error "Function does not return a value" for the function guessCorrect(). I do not understand why this happens or how to fix it.  Also, if you by chance happen to see any other errors please let me know.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

- I did try it with return but got the same outcome

Here is my code:

```
btnGuess.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, guessNumbers);

//Global Variables
var count = 0;

var myGuess:int;
var Answer:int;
var highNumber:int;
var lowNumber:int;

function guessNumbers(e:MouseEvent):void {
//Set Variables
 highNumber = int(txtinHighValue.text)
 lowNumber = int(txtinLowValue.text)

Answer = randomWholeNumber(highNumber, lowNumber);

myGuess = int(txtinGuess.text);

lblOutput.text = guessCorrect(myGuess, Answer, count);

}

function randomWholeNumber(highNumber:int,lowNumber:int):int
{

return Math.floor((highNumber - lowNumber + 1) * Math.random() + lowNumber);

}

**function guessCorrect(myGuess:int, Answer:int, count:int):String {
while (myGuess != Answer) {
    if (myGuess < Answer) {
        lblOutput.text = "Guess to low - try again!"
        count ++
    }
    else if (myGuess > Answer) {
        lblOutput.text = "Guess to high - try again!"
        count ++
    }
    else if (myGuess == Answer){
        lblOutput.text = "It's a match - you win!"
        count ++
    }
}
}**

lblGuesses.text = "Guessess: " += count

btnNewGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, guessNumbers); {
    count = 0;
    highNumber = 0;
    lowNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: `guessCorrect` directly affects `lblOutput.text` but should return the string value instead. Your function does not return anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a simple typo -- you forgot to put a `return string;` statement in your `guessCorrect` function.  My advice:  Spend more time working through some Actionscript tutorials until you understand functions a bit better.

Comment: The missing return in that function is not even the main problem.
That while loop will make it running forever the first time it's called, blocking and crashing the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a function ends in something other than `:void` such as your `:int` there needs to be a `return` line. Looks like:

```
function myFunction():int
{
    var myVar: int = 5;
    return myVar;
}
```